# Efficient 2d cumsum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, cumsum

Say I have an array like this

```
>>> a = np.arange(1,8).reshape((1,-1))
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

and I want to create, for each of the items in `a`, a "cumsum of the next 4 items". That is, my expected output is

```
1,       2,      3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
1+2,     2+3,     ...
1+2+3    2+3+4    ...
1+2+3+4  2+3+4+5  ...
```

i.e. a matrix that contains

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0
3, 5, 7, 9, 11,0, 0, 0
6, 9, 12,15,18,0, 0, 0
10,14,18,21,26,0, 0, 0
```

Since the cumsum operation cannot be correctly done for the last 3 items, I expect a `0` there. I know how to do a single cumsum. In fact, the arrays are

```
a[:4].cumsum().reshape((-1,1)); a[1:5].cumsum().reshape((-1,1))...
```

stacked horizontally. However, I don't know how to do this in an efficient way. What would be the nice vectorized numpy way of doing this? I'm also open for `scipy` packages, as long as they dominate `numpy` in terms of efficiency or readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way would to use a rolling window approach combined with `cumsum()`.

For example:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

a = np.arange(1, 9) # the starting array
slice_length = 4
```

Then you could write:

```
arr = as_strided(a, (slice_length, len(a)), (a.strides[0], a.strides[0])).cumsum(axis=0)
```

This gets you most of the way there, but to fill in the remaining `0` values, you can use slice and assign to get your desired output:

```
arr[:, (1-slice_length):] = 0
```

Then you have the array:

```
>>> arr
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  5,  7,  9, 11,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  9, 12, 15, 18,  0,  0,  0],
       [10, 14, 18, 22, 26,  0,  0,  0]])
```

I don't know if there is any way to produce exactly your desired output with one single vectorised method in NumPy (i.e. without the slicing). (`accumulateat`, a bit like `reduceat`, might be an interesting thing to add to NumPy's ufuncs...)

Comment: Right now, I prefer this answer more than the other, since I can simply do other calculations by e.g. changing `cumsum` to `cumprod`. However, it  seems to break down for a different starting array, such as `a = np.ones((1,8))`. Not sure what is happening, need to read up into strides first.

Comment: `strides` is just the number of bytes NumPy has to jump in memory to reach the next value in a row or column. My code snippet works for 1D inputs - you'll need to change it to something like `as_strided(a, (slice_length, a.shape[1]), (a.strides[1], a.strides[1]))` if `a` is 2D with one row.

Answer (score 2):

You can do your calculations efficiently using a simpler variant of a technique called [summed area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table), also known as integral image in image processing applications. First you calculate and store your summed area table, a complete cumsum of your first row with a `0` added in front:

```
a = np.arange(1, 8)
cs = np.concatenate(([0], np.cumsum(a)))
```

And you can now create each of your "cumsum of the next `n` items" as `cs[:n] - cs[:-n]`:

```
>>> for n in range(1, 5):
...     print n, '-->', (cs[n:] - cs[:-n])[:4]
...
1 --> [1 2 3 4]
2 --> [3 5 7 9]
3 --> [ 6  9 12 15]
4 --> [10 14 18 22]
```

You'll need to properly arrange them in the shape you want, but once the original calculation is done, you can compute each item of your output with a single subtraction, which is about as efficient as it can get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) like so -

```
In [53]: a
Out[53]: array([ 4, 13,  4, 18,  1,  2, 11, 15])

In [54]: WSZ = 4 # Window size

In [55]: idx = np.arange(WSZ)[:,None] + np.arange(a.size-WSZ+1) # Broadcasted indices

In [56]: a[idx].cumsum(axis=0) # Index into "a" & perform cumsum along axis-0
Out[56]: 
array([[ 4, 13,  4, 18,  1],
       [17, 17, 22, 19,  3],
       [21, 35, 23, 21, 14],
       [39, 36, 25, 32, 29]], dtype=int32)
```

Pad with zeros if needed -

```
In [57]: np.lib.pad(a[idx].cumsum(0),((0,0),(0,WSZ-1)),'constant',constant_values=0)
Out[57]: 
array([[ 4, 13,  4, 18,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [17, 17, 22, 19,  3,  0,  0,  0],
       [21, 35, 23, 21, 14,  0,  0,  0],
       [39, 36, 25, 32, 29,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```